# asfreq function for dataframes not working Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I've got a dataframe of all 505 stock from the SP500. I want to get the weekly values for each Sunday by using the asfreq function.
Let's say I'm only using it for two columns of AAPL and MSFT stock for just 20 trading days.

```
                 AAPL        MSFT
      Date      
2012-04-05  82.099293   27.453578
2012-04-09  82.429673   27.087763
2012-04-10  81.420407   26.539039
2012-04-11  81.130193   26.434521
2012-04-12  80.685799   26.983243
2012-04-13  78.413325   26.835175
2012-04-16  75.161385   27.070343
2012-04-17  78.992457   27.383899
2012-04-18  78.816259   27.122601
2012-04-19  76.108461   27.009374
2012-04-20  74.235032   28.237466
2012-04-23  74.069192   27.976170
2012-04-24  72.589626   27.801974
2012-04-25  79.031329   28.045851
2012-04-26  78.733339   27.967462
2012-04-27  78.124412   27.854232
2012-04-30  75.660185   27.889073
2012-05-01  75.420503   27.880361
2012-05-02  75.919303   27.697454
2012-05-03  75.380337   27.662615
```

I try on the dataframe the asfreq function.

```
df2 = df.asfreq("W-SUN", method="pad")
```

It generates this huge error that says at the bottom:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'
```

I also tried method = "ffill", same error. The asfreq("W-SUN") gave me only NaN values, and asfreq("W-MON", method="pad") also gave me the same error "W-SUN".

I've used the asfreq function before, and it worked perfectly, but now it doesn't. What gives? Any help would be very much appreciated.

​

​

​

​

Comment: `asfreq` works with `DatetimeIndex` what is the dtype of your index? try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` prior to the `asfreq` call

Comment: Hey EdChum, thanks replying, it worked! Very kind. I was perplexed as it worked fine before with exactly the same dataframe, the SP500 index that I've used many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html#pandas.DataFrame.asfreq) works with `DatetimeIndex`, the error is telling you that it's still `str` so you need to convert the `dtype` using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

then the call to `asfreq` should work as expected